# JTable single click select entire line of selected cell, double click edit row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a project where I have a JTable and :

- on single click on a row must select the entire line from jtable not only the clicked cell
- on double click on a cell that row must be editable

I use Netbeans IDE, if relevant.

The JTable code :

```
public class ModelTabelAbonati extends AbstractTableModel {

Abonat[] tabelAbonati = new Abonat[0];


public void Adauga (String nume, String prenume, String cnp, Integer telefon){
    tabelAbonati= Arrays.copyOf(tabelAbonati, tabelAbonati.length+1);
    tabelAbonati[tabelAbonati.length-1]=new Abonat (nume,prenume, cnp, telefon);
    fireTableRowsInserted(tabelAbonati.length-1, tabelAbonati.length-1);
}


public void Adauga(String nume, String prenume, String cnp, int telefon){
    tabelAbonati= Arrays.copyOf(tabelAbonati, tabelAbonati.length+1);
    tabelAbonati[tabelAbonati.length-1]=new Abonat (nume,prenume, cnp, telefon);
    fireTableRowsInserted(tabelAbonati.length-1, tabelAbonati.length-1);
}




@Override
public String getColumnName(int column){
    return new String[]{"Nr. ","Nume ","Prenume ","CNP ","Tel. Fix ","Tel. Mobil"}[column];
}


@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return tabelAbonati.length;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 6; 
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    Abonat a= tabelAbonati[rowIndex];

    switch (columnIndex){

    case 0: return rowIndex+1;
    case 1: return a.getNume();
    case 2: return a.getPrenume();
    case 3: return a.getCnp();
    case 4: return a.getTelefon().getTelFix();
    case 5: return a.getTelefon().getTelMobil();
    default: return "ERROR";


}

}

}
```

Comment: Congratulations.  Let us know if you have any problems getting your work done.

Comment: 1) *"on double click on a row that row must be editable"* sounds confusing... Do you mean row or cell? 2) *"on ligle click on a row must select the entire line from jtabel not only the clicked row"* Did you try `table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true)`? 3) For better help sooner post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry, my bad, on single click on a cell must select the entire row from jtabel of that cell (all the row must be blue). i tried table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true). it works but it doesn't select the entire row (turn in blue), it selects only the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to ModelTabelAbonati to allow edit cell:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }
```

Add this `table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true)`under `table = new Jtable()`